# Server testing a PHP app

Tags: php, testing, stress-testing

I have a PHP application that will be accepting image uploads and I'm expecting ~20,000 in about 2 days. I have no concept of how much traffic my server can handle... How would I go about simulating this beforehand to make sure it works ok? I know Rails has systems that make testing easy, but what tools might I use to simulate uploads and concurrent script processing on that scale?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is one of the best tools for load testing. I'm sure it can handle your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another great option is to write a php script that uses cUrl to repeatedly interact with the php engine, you can run multiple instances to see how it reacts.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home), it's a simple regression testing and benchmark utility.

Answer (score 0):

Some related posts, there are tons of tools out there to do this. The most popular open source load testing tools are OpenSTA and JMeter. But there are countless others.

[Best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)
[Open source Tool for Stress, Load and Performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507683/open-source-tool-for-stress-testing-load-testing-and-performance-testing)